# Problem with POST request to RESTful WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, post

I am trying to make a post request to my restful WCF service. The contract looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
               UriTemplate = "UploadMovie")]
    string UploadMovie(Stream stream);
```

or

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
               UriTemplate = "UploadMovie")]
    string UploadMovie(byte [] stream);
```

I am trying to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to make a request, yet I am not able to get it to work by putting some body in the request. What does the body need to look like? I have been writing the correct Json in the body but still no good...

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I am doing someting like {"stream" : data} as the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that i w as not setting the content-type in the post header