# Call to a post method in a RESTful wcf service

Tags: json, post, get, wcf-rest

I'm making a GET method, call it with link and everything is ok.
Here it is:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/myMethod/{input}",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
        )]
    MyClass myMethod(string input);
```

And here is the url with whom I'm calling it:
http://localhost:1234/Service1.svc/json/myMethod/blabla

However, when I'm making a post method, it doesn't work. Here is my POST method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
        )]
    MyClass anotherMethod(string comeOn);
```

and I call it with this link:
http://localhost:1234/Service1.svc/json/anotherMethod?comeOn=smthing
and it says Method not allowed.

How do I call a POST method?

Comment: Is this a duplicate question to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144166/problem-with-post-request-to-restful-wcf-service

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski No, I'm just asking for the url.

Comment: If you're asking for the URL, you are GETting the method. You can't POST by asking for a URL.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski That means that every method for which my client needs to enter the input, the method will be GET right?

Comment: No, you can control in your code whether you GET or POST to a method. Look in the second link that @rangitatanz provided.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski But how to make when my user is entering the inputs, not to enter them in an url, but in a form?

Comment: You need to provide a UI for that. You can do a web form or a client application for that.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski Since the POST methods' parameters are in the code, than the user can't enter them, right? So, every method which needs the user to enter an input is GET.

Comment: Да, така некако, but you can still pass the parameters from your web page or client application to the method you are calling.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski Фала :) So, I'll have a client application with a form and a template method which will take the input values from the form and will call the POST method with those values as arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the diff between a POST and a GET is that the GET you have all the params on the query string, whereas a POST has the params inside the message body of the request.

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_get_and_post_method_in_HTTP

Your second call is actually doing a GET hence why it's not allowing that method.

A way to test the post can be found here.

[How to simulate browser HTTP POST request and capture result in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071321/how-to-simulate-browser-http-post-request-and-capture-result-in-c-sharp)

Comment: That means that every method for which my client needs to enter the input, the method will be GET right?

Comment: No it should be a post. If you issue the request with all the params on the QS then it will be a GET. The HTTP methods are quite important for good restful design. With POST because the params are in the method body there is a much higher content limit that can be sent to the service. Is that what oyu are meaning?

Comment: @rangitaz But if the POST methods' parameters are in the code, that means that the user can't enter them, right? And that means that every method which need the user to enter an input is GET.

Comment: Ok so how are users calling these? If users are issuing the requests via a browser or something then yes it will be a GET. If they are filling in a form on a client and the client is posting the data via the service then it can be a POST. Here is an example of a JQuery client posting data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service#answer-485536

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to MSDN on working with REST web services.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx